# Laptop gets really hot then turns off, suspect it is overheating. How can I reduce this?

Tags: cooling, lenovo-laptop

My laptop keeps overheating and turning itself off. Underneath it gets really hot.

Even playing 3D online poker is impossible, it just overheats. If it is on my lap, I try and balance it so it's sitting just on my legs and has loads of free space under it. This seems to help a bit (it's never turned itself off in this position) but even being on a desk can result in it overheating.

There is a lot of dust, etc that I've cleaned it out (as much as I can easily take apart anyway), but it never used to happen. Any ideas?

The laptop is a Lenovo 3000 N200.

Answer (score 12):

Consider a laptop cooling pad:

[image]

Sorry, but I couldn't resist!

[image]

Comment: If you're male I propose using the second one at the office.

Comment: so *that's* what's wrong with you... knew there had to be something... ;)

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem a lot with my Toshiba laptop. I tried blowing out the dust and that didn't work. I tried a cooling pad, but it gets ***really***  annoying and severely limits portability.

What I did was to take it apart, replace the fan (which I think may have been faulty, it certainly had a lot of dust in it), remove the CPU, remove the old, dried up thermal grease, and apply new, high-quality, silver-based thermal grease.

Since then, I have not really had any problems with it. It only overheats after many hours of intense usage, compared to about five minutes before.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Undervolting](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=235824) your laptop.

Undervolting is a corollary of overclocking.  Overclocking involves running a chip faster - and possibly with higher voltages - than specified to get more performance.  Undervolting is running a chip at the same speed but at lower voltage which means less heat and longer battery life.

I'd had success using [RMClock](http://cpu.rightmark.org/products/rmclock.shtml) to do this.  I followed [this guide](http://www.nordichardware.com/Articles/?skrivelse=465).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Value-line/3000-N200-Overheating/td-p/33753;jsessionid=938D7E824A86B35DFC193C461563D75C) in the lenovo forums. It gives some suggestions based on your model. As Molly recommends, get a cooling pad so you don't burn your lap.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:

Step one: Air Compressor :D

Step two: Get a blade or something, jam it in the powered off laptop's fan (so it doesn't spin when you blow it).

Step three: Blow into the cooling exhaust.

If that doesn't work, you need to get an aftermarket 20 mm fan.